# Firestore document data extract

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection that has documents with two different structures;

1. document that has fields and sub-collections,
2. document that has fields with arrays.

When I try to extract data from the first document I get a well formatted JSON object. When I try to extract the 2nd document I get an `undefined` object

For example;

**document 1**

```
- BFld3O6MjcTYKmjW92
 |-Animals (subcoll)
 |  |- BGDTAD
 |  |   |- Name: "dog"
 |  |- BGDTAC
 |  |   |- Name: "cat"
 |- name: "Normal Pets and People"
 |- id: BFld3O6MjcTYKmjW92
```

**document 2**

```
- MyCustomDocument
 |- businessName: "Exotic Pets and Oddballs"
 |- id: 94869b7b-246e-4754-8d38-f95bba28b0b2
 |- Animals (array)
    [0] - Name: "lion"
    [1] - Name: "tiger"
```

I am requesting these using the Admin SDK within Typescript / react project;

```
import admin from 'firebase'

const config = {
  ...
  };

admin.initializeApp(config);
var db = admin.firestore(); 

const businessDoc: any = await db.collection('mybasecollection').doc("BFld3O6MjcTYKmjW92").get();
console.log(businessDoc.data()); // renders correctly

const businessDoc2: any = await db.collection('mybasecollection').doc("MyCustomDocument").get();
console.log(businessDoc2.data()); // undefined
```

Why would the 2nd document fail this way and how can I access the props from that document as a JSON object?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot from the Firebase console of the document that doesn't work. Be sure to include the path of the document in the screenshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I didn't want to reveal that level of information (including real keys, collection names etc) about my store. Is that really needed?

Comment: We need to be able to see that the names in your code match the names in the database.

Comment: Right now there's simply not enough to go on. You've simplified it so much, that the problem is unlikely to be in what is left. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Thanks both, I'll try and create a simple repo that I can share. thanks for getting back to me.